# Missing column when using read_excel to read from .xls file

Tags: r, excel, shiny, readxl

I am using the `R version 3.3.2` and latest `readxl` package. I am using the `read_excel` from `readxl` package for reading the .xls and .xlsx files.

In `Rstudio server` the `readxl` reads the .xls and .xlsx files correctly.

After deploying the application on the `Rshiny Pro server v1.5.2`, application is reading the `.xlsx` files correctly but while reading the `.xls` files it's not reading all the columns.

Also running `colnames(excel_data_frame)` returning nothing. By running `ncol(excel_data_frame)` I found out that the `excel_data_frame` is having `6 columns` against the `10 columns` in the .xls file. I am getting the actual number of rows though.

Can anyone guide me to solve this missing columns problem?

Comment: Can you share sample data for us to try?

Comment: Also did you try using `col_types` argument in `read_excel` to specify the column type of all columns and see if that reads all the columns?

Comment: Can't share the exact file as it's confidential. I did try col_types but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you used the read_excel() as follows:

```
read_excel(readxl_example(path))
```